# Bazel returns a rule linking error when building Tensorflow from source

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, bazel

I'm trying to get the InfoGAN code from GitHub to run, but when I try to build Tensorflow from the recommended source code, an error keeps on appearing. It runs fine for about 30 minutes and then crashes (even when sudo is used).

The error is as follows:

```
ERROR: /home/socialab/Desktop/tensorflow-master/tensorflow/python/BUILD:2436:1: Linking of rule '//tensorflow/python:gen_stateless_random_ops_py_wrappers_cc' failed (Exit 1)
bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/core/libop_gen_lib.a(op_gen_lib.o): In function `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::CreateInstance(google::protobuf::Arena*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const*)':
op_gen_lib.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf8internal14ArenaStringPtr14CreateInstanceEPNS0_5ArenaEPKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZN6google8protobuf8internal14ArenaStringPtr14CreateInstanceEPNS0_5ArenaEPKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x36): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaImpl::AllocateAlignedAndAddCleanup(unsigned long, void (*)(void*))'
```

When configuring Tensorflow I say no to almost everything (except for CUDA), like so:

```
WARNING: --batch mode is deprecated. Please instead explicitly shut down your Bazel server using the command "bazel shutdown".
You have bazel 0.29.1 installed.
Please specify the location of python. [Default is /usr/bin/python]: /usr/bin/python3


Found possible Python library paths:
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
Please input the desired Python library path to use.  Default is [/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages]
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with XLA JIT support? [Y/n]: n
No XLA JIT support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with OpenCL SYCL support? [y/N]: n
No OpenCL SYCL support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with ROCm support? [y/N]: n
No ROCm support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with CUDA support? [y/N]: y
CUDA support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with TensorRT support? [y/N]: n
No TensorRT support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Found CUDA 10.1 in:
    /usr/local/cuda/lib64
    /usr/local/cuda/include
Found cuDNN 7 in:
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
    /usr/include


Please specify a list of comma-separated CUDA compute capabilities you want to build with.
You can find the compute capability of your device at: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus.
Please note that each additional compute capability significantly increases your build time and binary size, and that TensorFlow only supports compute capabilities >= 3.5 [Default is: 7.5]: 7.5


Do you want to use clang as CUDA compiler? [y/N]: n
nvcc will be used as CUDA compiler.

Please specify which gcc should be used by nvcc as the host compiler. [Default is /usr/bin/gcc]: 


Please specify optimization flags to use during compilation when bazel option "--config=opt" is specified [Default is -march=native -Wno-sign-compare]: 


Would you like to interactively configure ./WORKSPACE for Android builds? [y/N]: n
Not configuring the WORKSPACE for Android builds.

Preconfigured Bazel build configs. You can use any of the below by adding "--config=<>" to your build command. See .bazelrc for more details.
    --config=mkl            # Build with MKL support.
    --config=monolithic     # Config for mostly static monolithic build.
    --config=ngraph         # Build with Intel nGraph support.
    --config=numa           # Build with NUMA support.
    --config=dynamic_kernels    # (Experimental) Build kernels into separate shared objects.
    --config=v2             # Build TensorFlow 2.x instead of 1.x.
Preconfigured Bazel build configs to DISABLE default on features:
    --config=noaws          # Disable AWS S3 filesystem support.
    --config=nogcp          # Disable GCP support.
    --config=nohdfs         # Disable HDFS support.
    --config=nonccl         # Disable NVIDIA NCCL support.
Configuration finished
```

I'm using the Bazel version that was recommended (0.29.1), CUDA 10.1, cudNN 7.6.4 and the 430.50 drivers. 
System specs:
Ubuntu 18.04
RTX 2080 Ti
i5-8600K
8GB RAM

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think Tensorflow only supports CUDA 10.0.

Comment: I Have encountered similar issue and by upgrading to the latest bazel and tensorflow releases it is resolved. Update it to the latest versions.